# How to find the necessary and sufficient condition for dim ker $F=\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V :=  \{f(x)= p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2 + p_3x^3 \mid p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3 \in \mathbb R\}.$

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$ and define $F: V \to V$ by $f(x) \mapsto af(x) + (bx + c)f'(x)$.

Then, I have to find the necessary and sufficient condition for $\dim\ker F = 0$.

At the pre-step of this, I had to calculate the representation matrix of $F$ about the base $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}.$ This is \begin{pmatrix}
a & c & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a+b & 2c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a+2b & 3c \\
0 &0&0&a+3b 
\end{pmatrix}

And I found the condition for $\dim \ker F = 0$ is $$a\neq 0\text{ and } a+b\neq 0 \text{ and } a+2b\neq 0 \text{ and } a+3b\neq0$$ (This may be mistaken.)

I found this necessary and sufficient condition  without using the representation matrix, but I think that I can find this necessary and sufficient condition  more easily using the representation matrix.

Actually, the condition $a\neq 0, a+b\neq 0, a+2b\neq 0, a+3b\neq0$ is  the situation that all the diagonal components of the representation matrix is not zero, so I think the condition for $\dim \ker F = 0$ is related to the representation matrix.

How can I use the representation matrix in  order to find the condition for $\dim \ker F = 0$?

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to get with this, you pretty much solved it already. Let $A$ be your representation matrix. Then the kernel of $F$ corresponds to the nullspace of $A$, which is trivial if and only if $\det(A)\neq 0$. But $\det(A) = a(a+b)(a+2b)(a+3b)$.

Comment: The goal should be either $\dim\ker F=0$ or $\ker F=\{0\}$.